# Adjusting/Forcing Z-Indexes with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I am designing an alternate flat version of a 3D solar system piece for IE (because the transitions are a no go in IE for now) but I am having a lot of trouble with the Z-index in IE.  The indexes work perfectly in the 3D webkit version.

I have tried manually adjusting the z-indexes for the IE css but the divs just won't move.  I need another set of eyes.

This is the link to the JSBin for the entire piece.  http://jsbin.com/sagix/1/edit

Each planet is activated when you click on the corresponding option in the navigation menu.  The problem I am having is that once a planet is active there is a hover call.  But the hover call for planets on the left (parenting, stress, spirituality) are not responding when I hover because of the z-indexes.

So my thought was to try it with JQuery.  If it isn't happening in CSS can I force a div forward with JQuery on click?

If I can force it forward would this be the proper syntax (this is the only external custom JS in the piece.  it is http://secure.cart32.com/WarrenKahn/scripts.min3.js)?

```
$(window).load(function(){var e=$("body"),t=$("#universe"),n=$("#solar-system"),r=function()
{e.removeClass("view-2D opening").addClass("view-3D").delay(500).queue(function()  
{$(this).removeClass("hide-UI").addClass("set-speed");

$(this).dequeue()})},i=function(e){t.removeClass().addClass(e)};
$("#toggle-data").click(function(t){e.toggleClass("data-open data-close");
t.preventDefault()});
$("#toggle-controls").click(function(t){e.toggleClass("controls-open controls-close");
t.preventDefault()});
$("#data a").click(function(e){var t=$(this).attr("class");
n.removeClass().addClass(t);
$(this).parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).parent().css('z-index', 1000);
e.preventDefault()});
$(".set-view").click(function(){e.toggleClass("view-3D view-2D")});
$(".set-zoom").click(function(){e.toggleClass("zoom-large zoom-close")});
$(".set-speed").click(function(){i("scale-stretched set-speed")});
$(".set-size").click(function(){i("scale-s set-size")});
$(".set-distance").click(function(){i("scale-d set-distance")});r()});
```

Then there is a close button on the hover div.  Can I add the same zindex Jquery to the close button to return it to a lower value?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ca-close1").click(function(){
    $("#descriptionls").fadeOut()
  $('#mercury .infos').css('z-index', 1000);
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: my solution below is working in IE 11 the only thing I noticed is that 2 of the 5 separate photos in your mouseOver triggered banners (1 photo/banner) do not load for some reason which is a separate unrelated issue. I put in 2.5 hours to solve your specific issue. Do you have any feedback at all?

Comment: Of course I will have feedback.  It's just 9am in Los Angeles.  I'm going to grab some coffee and get started.I haven't had any problems with the pictures loading at all though.  The only issue I was having was mouseover on left.  The 3D version of this works perfectly and is essentially the same exact code with all of the Preserve 3D and key frame animations removed.

Comment: Sweet! Glad it worked! let me know if you have other issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [DEMO](http://www.totallytotallyamazing.com/jsFiddle/planet/planet.html#). Let me know if this fixes your problem. You could just copy the code from under the hood of my DEMO site?

I changed your following HTML:

```
<div id="data">
    <a class="mercury" title="LIFE SKILLS" href="#mercuryspeed" onMouseOver="zOnEvent('mercury', 1);" onMouseOut="zOnEvent('mercury', 2);">LIFE SKILLS</a>
    <a class="jupiter" title="CAREER" href="#jupiterspeed" onMouseOver="zOnEvent('jupiter', 1);" onMouseOut="zOnEvent('jupiter', 2);">CAREER</a>
    <a class="venus" title="PARENTING" href="#venusspeed" onMouseOver="zOnEvent('venus', 1);" onMouseOut="zOnEvent('venus', 2);">PARENTING</a>
    <a class="saturn" title="STRESS" href="#saturnspeed" onMouseOver="zOnEvent('saturn', 1);" onMouseOut="zOnEvent('saturn', 2);">STRESS</a>
    <a class="uranus" title="SPIRITUALITY" href="#uranusspeed" onMouseOver="zOnEvent('uranus', 1);" onMouseOut="zOnEvent('uranus', 2);">SPIRITUALITY</a>
</div>
```

I added my JS function:

```
function zOnEvent(cl, cond) {
    if (cond === 1) {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
        for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
            element[i].style.zIndex = '97';
        }
    } else if (cond === 2) {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
        for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
            element[i].style.zIndex = '10';
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the following sections of your CSS code:

```
.sun #sun .infos,
.mercury #mercury .infos,
.venus #venus .infos,
.earth #earth .infos,
.mars #mars .infos,
.jupiter #jupiter .infos,
.saturn #saturn .infos,
.uranus #uranus .infos,
.neptune #neptune .infos {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
-o-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
-ms-transform: rotateX(0deg); 
transform: rotateX(0deg); 
   z-index:97;
}

.mercury #mercury.orbit,
.venus #venus.orbit,
.earth #earth.orbit,
.mars #mars.orbit,
.jupiter #jupiter.orbit,
.saturn #saturn.orbit,
.uranus #uranus.orbit,
.neptune #neptune.orbit {
    border: 0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    z-index:97;
}

#data {
    position: fixed;
    top: 515px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```